# Is state defined for non-equilibrium systems?

Tags: thermodynamics, equilibrium

Equilibrium thermodynamic states follow the state principle and Gibb's phase rule when it comes to fixing a state when given a minimum of (typically) 2 state properties. For non-equilibrium states, I believe we can still define state properties for these states (like pressure, temperature, enthalpy, free energy etc.). I'm not sure if metastable states like supercooled liquid is considered a non-equilibrium state, but can we still fix the state of supercooled liquid by knowing say, pressure and temperature to find other state properties? What about unstable states like an activated complex in reacting systems?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-equilibrium_thermodynamics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For metastable systems this can be done. In case of supercooled or superheated liquids, the Gibbs free energy will be the analytic continuation from the liquid in the stable phase. In equilibrium the liquid would not be there because the specific Gibbs energy for the solid or gas would be lower. If you follow the liquid into the regime when it should have turned into a gas, then because you don't encounter a phase transition, the Gibbs free energy cannot have singular behavior. It must therefore be an analytic function (note that infinite differentiable but non-analytic behavior would correspond to a so-called "infinite order phase transition", so if we assume that there is no phase transition, the Gibbs free energy must be analytic).

All the properties of the liquid follow from the Gibbs free energy, so in principle you can compute the properties of supercooled or superheated liquids using only the properties in the normal state.

Comment: For metastable systems, can we fix the state using pressure and temperature alone (i.e. express h, u as functions of (T,P))? However for unstable states like a transition state or a system with thermal gradients this would not be possible?

Comment: For metastable states, you can introduce constraints that  make the state stable. Simple, rather trivial example: A container containing oxygen and nitorgen in separate compartments is technically not in equilibrium, if they were let to mix with each otehr then the entropy would increase. If oxygen and nirogen very slowly leaks through the boundaries then that equilibrium would eventually be reached all by itself.

Comment: Similarly, if you have superheated water e.g. by heating water above the boiling point in a microwave without a turntable, then what happens is that the configuration the water molecules initially in are effectively sampled from a set that doesn;t incklude the vastly larger set of states corresponding to the water having turned into vapor. This will happen spontaneously, but if you don't shake the cup of water it can take some time. If you were to model this matastable state, you could image an imaginary boundary in the copnfiguration space limiting the water to be in liquid form.

Comment: In case of thermal gradients, you don't have thermal equilibrium, so you have to take into account that thermodynamics will be violated to some degree.

Comment: For the case of metastable state, using the above approach we should be able to get u, h, s etc. if we know T and p, much like for equilibrium systems? I'm assuming we can't do this for unstable states (like activated complex).